# How to compare multiple enums using Reflection without know the enum type in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

My project have multiple enums and some classes have more than one enum as attribute.
I need to create a log that shows the previous values and the new values when a object is edited. I know to compare normal fields as String, Integer, etc... but I can't do this using enum.

I was comparing this way, but doen'st work with enum:

```
public static Map<Object, List<Object>> compareObjects(Object a, Object b){
 ...Some varibles declaration
  Field[] fieldsA a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  Field[] fieldsB b.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

int i = 0;
 for(; i < a.length; i++){
    ...some codintions
    if(fieldsA[i].get(a).equals(fieldsB[i].get(b)){

    ...
```

Comment: An enum literal has no meaning without its declaring type, it's just a string. Unless you know which `enum` type it belongs to, you can't do it.

Comment: Can you perhaps show your classes and the code from which you need to compare?

Comment: How would you compare these enum values if you did know their actual type?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to handling enums:

```
Object v1 = fields1[i].get(o1);
Object v2 = fields2[i].get(o2);
if (fields1[i].getType().isEnum()) {
    v1 = fields1[i].getType().getName() + '#' + v1;
}
if (fields2[i].getType().isEnum()) {
    v2 = fields2[i].getType().getName() + '#' + v2;
}

if (v1.equals(v2)) {
    System.out.println("Field #" + i + " matches");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Field #" + i + " changed from \"" + v1 + "\" to \"" + v2);
}
```

For example, given these enums:

```
enum Color { Red, Green, Blue; }
enum RGB { Red, Green, Blue; }
```

comparing a field that is `Color.Red` with a field that is `RGB.Red` will fail, because what is actually compared is "Color#Red" and "RGB#Red".

That said, you probably have much bigger issues ahead. The documentation for `getDeclaredFields()` says:

> The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

So you could be comparing two equivalent objects, but your test will fail if `getDeclaredFields` returns the fields in different order. At the very least, you need to sort the fields by `getName()` so you have a consistent order. Also, compare the names before comparing values, so you know you are comparing `x` to 'x', and not `x` to `y`.

Comment: getEnumConstants can be used to get this in order - and then you can use .name to compare. But what about enum that have this same constants - but also they have other fields. Like `RGB` enum would also define `int value` field for each enum constant.